# How to put values in each bar of the barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this df:

```
df2 <- structure(list(group = c("Suicidio", "Soledad", "Preocupacion", 
                                "Sin Amigos"), EMSE_2012 = c(6, 7.6, 6.5, -1.8), 
                      EMSE_2018 = c(15.7,13.9, 10.5, -0.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

and I need that each value of the bar is in the center of the bar:

```
p <- df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
p + labs(title  = "Diferencia de medias entre hombres y mujeres. Indicadores EMSE, 2012 y 2018", 
         y = "Prevalencia",fill = "Edición", x = "Factores de Riesgo de Salud Mental")
p + geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 4, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- structure(list(group = c("Suicidio", "Soledad", "Preocupacion", 
                                "Sin Amigos"), EMSE_2012 = c(6, 7.6, 6.5, -1.8), 
                      EMSE_2018 = c(15.7,13.9, 10.5, -0.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

p <- df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')

p + labs(title  = "Diferencia de medias entre hombres y mujeres. Indicadores EMSE, 2012 y 2018", 
         y = "Prevalencia",fill = "Edición", x = "Factores de Riesgo de Salud Mental")

p + geom_text(aes(label = value),
              position = position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

Comment: Yes! I needed the values in the center of the bar! Thank you!